# XML Deserializing "Element was not expected" error

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I know this has been asked before, but I checked the other threads and none were of help to me. I am trying to deserialize an xml to an object and am getting the error:

```
"<doPublish xmlns='http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1'> 
   was not expected."
```

My XML looks like:

```
<lexspd:doPublish xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1 ../xsd/lexs/publish-discover/3.1/publish-discover.xsd"
    xmlns:lexspd="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1"
    xmlns:lexs="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/3.1">
    <lexs:PublishMessageContainer>
        <lexs:PublishMessage>
            <lexs:PDMessageMetadata>
            </lexs:PDMessageMetadata>
        </lexs:PublishMessage>
    </lexs:PublishMessageContainer>
</lexspd:doPublish>
```

The code I am using to deserialize with looks like:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PublishMessageType));
Encoding encode = new UTF8Encoding();

PDWebService lexpdServiceProxy = new PDWebService();
lexpdServiceProxy.Url = "http://59.60.72.12/";

String pdMessageXml = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

DoPublishType doPublishType = new DoPublishType();
MemoryStream publishMsgMemStream = new MemoryStream(encode.GetBytes(pdMessageXml));
doPublishType.PublishMessageContainer = new PublishMessageType[1];
doPublishType.PublishMessageContainer[0] =
   (PublishMessageType)xs.Deserialize(publishMsgMemStream);
```

And the object I am trying to deserialize too looks like: (shortened version)

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "PDWebServiceSoapBinding", Namespace = "http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1/ws")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(SRMessageType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(AugmentationType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(PayloadObjectReferenceType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ComplexObjectType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(MetadataType))]
public partial class PDWebService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback doPublishOperationCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    public PDWebService()
    {
        this.Url = "http://localhost:9080/PDWebService/services/PDWebServiceBean";
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public event doPublishCompletedEventHandler doPublishCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("urn:#doPublish", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("doPublishReponse", Namespace = "http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1/ws")]
    public doPublishReponse doPublish([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("doPublish", Namespace = "http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1")] DoPublishType doPublish1)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("doPublish", new object[] {
                doPublish1});
        return ((doPublishReponse)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.IAsyncResult BegindoPublish(DoPublishType doPublish1, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return this.BeginInvoke("doPublish", new object[] {
                doPublish1}, callback, asyncState);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public doPublishReponse EnddoPublish(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        object[] results = this.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
        return ((doPublishReponse)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void doPublishAsync(DoPublishType doPublish1)
    {
        this.doPublishAsync(doPublish1, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void doPublishAsync(DoPublishType doPublish1, object userState)
    {
        if ((this.doPublishOperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.doPublishOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OndoPublishOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("doPublish", new object[] {
                doPublish1}, this.doPublishOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OndoPublishOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.doPublishCompleted != null))
        {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.doPublishCompleted(this, new doPublishCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public new void CancelAsync(object userState)
    {
        base.CancelAsync(userState);
    }
}
    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1/ws")]
public partial class doPublishReponse
{

    private string responseStausField;

    private doPublishReponseErrorDetails errorDetailsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string responseStaus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.responseStausField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.responseStausField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public doPublishReponseErrorDetails errorDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.errorDetailsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.errorDetailsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("doPublish", Namespace = "http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1", IsNullable = true)]
```

To the top of the class I am trying to deserialize too, with no luck. 
I have also tried changing the XmlSerializer object to:

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "doPublish";
xRoot.Namespace = "http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PublishMessageType), xRoot);
```

This would work, but every type in the deserialized object would return null, even though they are all populated in the xml document.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Could you give the name of the class you want to (de)serialize ? Is it doPublishReponse ? 

If so, I don't see 
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(doPublishReponse))] anywhere in your proxy class

Comment: The name of the class is PDWebService. I willadd the doPublishResponse class as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put your xml into a file 'test.xml' and then ran xsd test.xml.
This resulted in 'test.xsd' and 'test_app1.xsd'.
I added the schema elements from test_app1.xsd to test.xsd and then ran xsd.test.xsd /classes.

This resulted in:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/3.1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/3.1", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class PublishMessageContainer {

    private PublishMessageContainerPublishMessage[] publishMessageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PublishMessage")]
    public PublishMessageContainerPublishMessage[] PublishMessage {
        get {
            return this.publishMessageField;
        }
        set {
            this.publishMessageField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/3.1")]
public partial class PublishMessageContainerPublishMessage {

    private string pDMessageMetadataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PDMessageMetadata {
        get {
            return this.pDMessageMetadataField;
        }
        set {
            this.pDMessageMetadataField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/3.1")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/3.1", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class doPublish {

    private PublishMessageContainer[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PublishMessageContainer")]
    public PublishMessageContainer[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now running the following code in LINQPad, works fine.

```
using(var stream = File.Open(@"..path here..\test.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "doPublish";
    xRoot.Namespace = "http://usdoj.gov/leisp/lexs/publishdiscover/3.1";
    xRoot.IsNullable = true;

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(doPublish), xRoot);

    var root = (doPublish)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

    root.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, but after I publish the doPublish object to the Web Service, the web service returns "FAIL" and strangely, say that the PublishMessageType is null. Even though it is populated when I view the object in Visual Studio debug mode. How the code was originally setup was the XmlSerializer would deserialize to a typeof PublishMessageType. Any thoughts on how to get it to deserialize to the a type of PublishMessageType?

Comment: Is there a public URL so that I can add a service reference?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the namespace needs to be the same in both cases. The rejected piece of XML is missing "/ws" at the end.

Comment: I tried removing the ws from the PDWebService class and it still gave the same error.